# How to convert a project from npm to yarn by default

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg

My project was initialized using npm and for a long time I had been working with npm, now I wanted to switch to yarn, since this solves some problems, the question is how to create-react-app so that by default it offers to update using yarn instead of npm

That is, yes, I can update my packages with yarn, but I would like create-react-app itself to offer an update using yarn

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to have yarn installed in your computer.
Follow instruction on https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install

Then, create-react-app will use yarn by default, as explained here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/#selecting-a-package-manager

**Note:**
If you are trying to update an already existing app, then delete package-lock.json and node_modules, and install dependencies again with yarn:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
yarn install // will create a new yarn.lock file
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
yarn create <starter-kit-package> [<args>]
```

e.g:

```
$ yarn global add create-react-app
```

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create/

Answer (score 0):

I just delete npm from my project and leave only yarn localy and its work fine